# Netplan bridge master getting a static IP address instead of the bridge

Tags: networking, 20.04, netplan, network-bridge, systemd-networkd

I am trying to configure a bridge for KVM guests and host connectivity. The bridge is never configured right, the physical NIC always ends up getting the static IP address and the bridge is assigned a dynamic one. The static IP is reserved in the router which may be whats causing this but I do not want to remove the DHCP reservation. Is there something I am not doing right?

This is what my Netplan config looks like:

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: NetworkManager
    ethernets:
        enp2s0:
            dhcp4: no
            dhcp6: no
    bridges:
        br0:
            dhcp4: no
            dhcp6: no
            interfaces: [enp2s0]
            gateway4: 192.168.0.1
            addresses: [192.168.0.100/24]
            macaddress: 40:b0:34:30:c5:bf # Same as the physical NIC
            nameservers:
                addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
            parameters:
                stp: false
                forward-delay: 0
```

`netplan --debug apply` output: https://pastebin.com/9yfMfWj0

`ip route` output:

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp2s0 src 192.168.0.100 metric 202 
default via 192.168.0.1 dev br0 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.101 metric 230 
169.254.0.0/16 dev br-c87c70358e53 scope link src 169.254.162.89 metric 207 
169.254.0.0/16 dev docker0 scope link src 169.254.164.22 metric 208 
169.254.0.0/16 dev veth66c4130 scope link src 169.254.120.192 metric 210 
169.254.0.0/16 dev veth97ef893 scope link src 169.254.172.222 metric 212 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-c87c70358e53 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 
172.25.0.0/16 dev br-a88b0c435e9a proto kernel scope link src 172.25.0.1 linkdown 
172.26.0.0/16 dev br-bbd6b452a7d7 proto kernel scope link src 172.26.0.1 linkdown 
172.28.0.0/16 dev br-7f9c923a0aa0 proto kernel scope link src 172.28.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp2s0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.0.100 metric 202 
192.168.0.0/24 dev br0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.0.101 metric 230
```

**EDIT 1:**

I have tried using networkd and disabled NetworkManager however, I face the same issue. I noticed that the bridge is assigned the static IP listed and a secondary one as well but the static IP is also assigned to the physical card.

`ip addr` output:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 40:b0:34:30:c5:bf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.100/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global noprefixroute enp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
12: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 40:b0:34:30:c5:bf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.100/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.0.101/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global secondary noprefixroute br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2607:fea8:c40:5d30::77c0/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 140769sec preferred_lft 140769sec
    inet6 2607:fea8:c40:5d30:42b0:34ff:fe30:c5bf/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 172799sec preferred_lft 172799sec
    inet6 2607:fea8:c40:5d30:ef6d:24e5:94a9:fc6a/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 172799sec preferred_lft 172799sec
    inet6 fe80::fded:8289:a1a3:580b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using the NetworkManager backend, instead of the default networkd backend?  In the past we've seen NetworkManager's bridge support is not as mature as networkd's, so it's possible you're encountering a NetworkManager bug.

Comment: I have cockpit (server front end) running and it uses NetworkManager for network stats. Its not a problem for me use networkd so I'll try the config with that and and see if the issue persists.

Comment: Switching the renderer to networkd did not help, I still have the same behaviour for the interfaces.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am seeing similar behavior.